# Creating a thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

How would I go about in creating a thread in C#?

In java I would either implement the Runnable interface

```
class MyThread implements Runnable{
public void run(){
//metthod
}
```

and then

```
MyThread mt = new MyThread;
Thread tt = new Thread(mt);
tt.start()
```

or I could simply extend the Thread class

```
class MyThread extends Thread{
public void run(){
//method body
}
```

and then

```
MyThread mt = new MyThread
mt.start();
```

Comment: Removing the `[java]` as the answer won't be about Java (it is only mentioned in the question)

Comment: There are many ways to do so. I suggest taking a look at [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) by Josef Albahari. It is a good primer, though somewhat dated (the TPL will not be mentioned, for example).

Comment: If you try to search with your favorite search engine on `C# Thread` you will find a innumerable list of links. Starting, of course, with [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, contrary to Java, in .NET you can't extend the [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) class because it's sealed.

So to execute a function in a new thread the most naive way is to manually spawn a new thread and pass it the function to be executed (as anonymous function in this case):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => 
{
    // put the code here that you want to be executed in a new thread
});
thread.Start();
```

or if you don't want to use an anonymous delegate then define a method:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    // put the code here that you want to be executed in a new thread
}
```

and then within the same class start a new thread passing the reference to this method:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(SomeMethod);
thread.Start();
```

and if you want to pass parameters to the method:

```
public void SomeMethod(object someParameter)
{
    // put the code here that you want to be executed in a new thread
}
```

and then:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(SomeMethod);
thread.Start("this is some value");
```

---

That's the native way to execute tasks in background threads. To avoid paying the high price of creating new threads you could use one of the threads from the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() =>
{
    // put the code here that you want to be executed in a new thread
});
```

or using an [asynchronous delegate execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb.aspx):

```
Action someMethod = () =>
{
    // put the code here that you want to be executed in a new thread
};
someMethod.BeginInvoke(ar => 
{
    ((Action)ar.AsyncState).EndInvoke(ar);
}, someMethod);
```

---

And yet another, and more modern way to execute such tasks is to use the TPL (starting from .NET 4.0):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    // put the code here that you want to be executed in a new thread
});
```

So, yeah, as you can see, there are like gazzilions of techniques that could be used to run a bunch of code on a separate thread.

Comment: As additional information, you can also create a thread that repeats itself at a specified interval using the `Timer` thread class.

Comment: @Joe, yeah, as I said, there are like gazzilion ways to execute some task on a background thread. People have written entire books on this subject. It's hard to cover them all in a single SO answer. I just gave some tips to the OP, so that he could pursue his research and hopefully ask a more concrete question next time.

Comment: Indeed. I was just pointing out the Timer to the OP since it's useful to know, and also to ensure he doesn't add a sleep of some sort in his thread to mimic the Timer ;)